# How do I add a caffe slice layer to crop images?

Tags: deep-learning, caffe

For example instead of inferring a batch of 64 28x28 images and adding 64 results together why can I add a layer to the network and crop out these 64 images from a 224x224 input image? It seems this would be more elegant and faster. 
[gif of different lighting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bp0tl.gif)

How do you do this? I find it odd I can’t find slice examples like this and I am guess I must be using the wrong terms or someone asking the question wrong.

I tried the slice layer but it keep wanting to slice the 8 bit gray. For example to create four 224x224 2bit images.

Any Ideas?

By the way my application is really cool! I am doing unsupervised grouping of 3D objects using many different lighting angles. This eliminates manual labeling of classes! 
https://github.com/GemHunt/lighting-augmentation

Thanks Much! Paul Krush

Answer (score 0):

This was answered for now on the Caffe Google Group:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/caffe-users/_uii8kTMOdM

**One or more of these answers will work for me:**

1.) Python pre and post processing is better

2.) Check out windowing

3.) Try the reshape layer (1,1,224,224)->(1,64,28,28)